# Do same task but on two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how to do next task.

I have my code where I copy cells from my main File and create a new sheet and paste it. What I was wondering to know is how can a reply this task and do it on two sheets. I mean, copy cells from main File and the create two sheets and paste cell on both sheets that were created.

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "005" 'Creates a new sheet to work with FPY 005 data
Sheets.Add.Name = "Second 005" 'Creates a new sheet to work with FY 005 data
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Sheets("005").Range("A1") 'Copy information filtered and paste it on new sheet created
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Second 005").Range("A1") 'Same as code line above
```

Greeting

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the values from one sheet to another use

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Works smoother.

To create a new sheet use below code. It adds new sheet AFTER the specific sheet.

`Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("AfterWhatSheet")).Name = "NewSheetName"`